# Homescreen touch event in android

Tags: android, android-activity, homescreen

I got a problem during my app development.
According to my application requirement
1.Whenever the user touch or click or long pressed on home screen.
2.I have to change the shared preference values in my application but unable to found out the solution. Any suggestion
I hope my problem is clear to you

Comment: witch type value u want to change?

Comment: I ant to change integervalue

Comment: your problem is when your apps go in onpause then u want change the value?am i right?

Comment: it has to consider whether it is in pause state or in destroy state

Comment: have you got the solution for this? if yes then pls share